# how to maximize the easygui message box as default

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi2, easygui

I'm using easygui in my final year project. Is there any way i can set the message box maximize as default. Right now it's too big for my 2.8' touch screen display. This is my sample code-

```
`while True:                                                                                        
colorWipe(strip, Color(255, 0, 0))  # Red wipe
colorWipe(strip, Color(0, 255, 0))  # Blue wipe
colorWipe(strip, Color(0, 0, 255))  # Green wipe
msgbox( "Press OK to continue", "Welcome to COMPU-GAUGE")
dim1 = integerbox(msg="Enter first dimension")
qn1 = integerbox(msg="Enter quantity",choices=('Back','OK'))
colorWipe(strip, Color(0, 0, 0))  # Red wipe `
```

I'm using a WS2812b LED strip in this project.

Thanks for all the help

Comment: do you have any sample code?

Comment: @NoamHacker I have added my sample code above